# How to find an array that is stored in another array with Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like this:

```
{
    "name" : "test",
    "modules" : [ 
        {
            "moduleName" : "Module 1",
            "chapters" : [ 
                {
                    "chapterName" : "Chapter 1",
                    "questions" : [ 
                        {
                            "title" : "Is this a question?",
                            "answers" : [ 
                                {
                                    "answer" : "Yes"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "answer" : "No"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "answer" : "Maybe"
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ]
                }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Now I would like to get the all the values that a specific chapter array includes. So for example, I want to have everything that's stored in the chapter array named "Chapter 1". Is there a smooth way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get every chapter as a separate document but before you can run [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to filter out as many documents as possible. The same $match can be run once again to keep only `Chapter 1` subdocuments after `$unwind`. In the last step you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote your chapter to a root level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "modules.chapters.chapterName": "Chapter 1" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$modules"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$modules.chapters"
    },
    {
        $match: { "modules.chapters.chapterName": "Chapter 1" }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$modules.chapters" }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XzUslcO8XUC)